# How to fix "no such partition" error in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue

I'm a rookie to Ubuntu. Before I installed Ubuntu, I had Windows 7. Then I completely wiped the disk (500 GB) using GParted and installed Ubuntu 14.04 with following partitions:

```
/ of 30gb
swap of 4gb
/home of 160gb
```

The remaining space is `unallocated`.

But my Ubuntu freezes frequently. 
Now I got the following screen:

[image: errors screen]

and I got these errors:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >
grub rescue >
grub rescue >
grub rescue >
grub rescue >
```

Anyone please help me out.

Comment: What brand/model system, or what are specs? Did you shut system off while running or have power failure? That often requires a fsck to repair. But may be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with GRUB or Linux. It's a hardware issue. Probably you are using cheap cables that don't connect properly or have dirty contacts. It's also possible that your drive has gone bad (the electronics on it, not the media), or even your host adapter. Did you try connecting to another machine, or connecting a different drive (if not, why not?)

On a different topic: there is no point in having separate root and /home partitions.

Comment: Occasionally it is a hardware issue. First check connections. But more often something software related. And many like separate /home as it is easier to install a new version. I often suggest it, but I also use smaller / (root) partition and large /mnt/data partition to separate system from data. What is left in my /home is almost all the hidden user settings and .wine, so do keep /home inside / partition.